# Check which module depends on other in node

Tags: node.js, npm, node-inspector

I just installed the latest node LTS version for the moment (8.9.0).
`npm install` fails since node-inspector does not supported in this version of node, as stated by its maintainers.

I wish to check which modules are using node-inspector, so I'll might be able to remove/replace them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `npm ls` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running

```
npm ls node-inspector
```

inside your project will print you a dependency tree, highlighting the dependencies using node-inspector

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls